# After creating swap partition, LTS won't recognize new partition

Tags: 12.04, swap

I downgraded my system from 13.04 to 12.04, and in the processes messed up cryptswap.

Each time i booted, i would get a warning about cryptswap not being there, so I deleted cryptswap using a [tutorial i found here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3awww.logilab.org/blogentry/29155&hl=en&tbo=d&strip=1)

and added a swap partition using tutorial here

now, the system recognizes that I have a swap partition, but does not load it. This is my understanding. My Boot-Info details are here [Boot info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5868155/)

How do i get the computer to recognize the swap partition?

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit `/etc/fstab` and add an entry for your new swap partition

Modify the line:

```
UUID=4b1e51e4-03f2-447f-94a8-6890006b7ef7  none swap sw 0 0
```

remove (comment out) the other line

```
#/dev/sda7 none swap sw 0  0
```

Save the changes and run `swapon`

```
sudo swapon
```

Post any error messages you have.

See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_do_I_add_more_swap.3F